# Ordenar 3 arrays de acordo o primeiro array

Tags: php, classificação, order

Eu tenho 3 arrays separados em $students, $sites, $consideracoes. Eu estou tentando ordenar a minha saida de dados pelo array $students. Quando  eu ordendo o array $students, o outros dois arrays que possuem vinculo linha para linha com o array $students ficam incorretos.

Como eu facao para ordenar o array $students e este refletir nos outros dois arrays $sites, $consideracoes?

Meus arrays:

```
Array $students
(
    [0] => Stew2 Dent
    [1] => Stew1 Dent
    [2] => Stew5 Dent
    [3] => Stew4 Dent
)
******Array $sites
(
    [1] =>      GRH
    [2] =>      STB     GRH
    [3] =>      STB     GRH
    [4] =>      GRH     CON
)
******Array $consideracoes
(
    [0] =>           LT          WF          BA          PE
    [1] =>           BA
    [2] =>           LT          PE
    [3] =>           LT          PE
)
```

Esse e o meu codigo. Eu tentei usar asort, mas nao esta funcionando.

```
function printPDF($students, $sites, $considerations)
{ 
    $marginLeft=15;
    $marginRight=15;
    $marginTop=25;
    $pdf = new PDF(); 
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L'); 
    $pdf->SetMargins($marginLeft, $marginTop,  $marginRight, true);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $marginTop);
    $fileOutput= "Report.pdf";
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica','',  10);
    $lineX=12; //space btw answers
    $lineY=5;
    $id=0;

   asort($students, $sites);

for ($i=0; $i <count($sites); $i++) 
    {
        $pdf->SetX($marginLeft+10 );
        $pdf->Cell($lineX,$lineY,++$id,0,0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell($lineX+22,$lineY,$students[$i],0,0,'L');

        $pdf->Cell($lineX+80,$lineY,$sites[$i+1],0,0,'L');

        $pdf->Cell($lineX+100,$lineY,$considerations[$i],0,1,'L');
    }

$pdf->Output('reports/'.$fileOutput, 'F');

}
```

Comment: Pessoalmente acho que não tem a representação ideal de informação o que lhe complica drasticamente o que pretende fazer. Bem melhor e mais simples era ter um array de objetos  em que cada objeto tem a informação do aluno, ou um array de arrays em que cada linha (ou subarray) tem a informação do aluno. Assim quando ordena vai tudo junto e o problema nem sequer existe.

Comment: Eu tenho um array, mas como tenho linhas em brando nao consigo usar usort.

Comment: Você não tem 1 array, tem 3 arrays distintos que na verdade estão todos relacionados entre si.

Comment: Sim. linha com linha. Alguma sugestao de como eu posso fazer para ordena-los?